# I get notified of my own Suggested Edits for review

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reviewing, notifications

I believe the functionality behind the review notification doesn't check the Suggested Edit's User Id against the logged in User's Id to determine whether you should be reviewing your own edit. The actual review process seems to pick it up however, as it doesn't offer me any review tasks upon clicking.

This came about as I'd just submitted a Suggested Edit to the [world-of-warcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-of-warcraft) tag wiki (and excerpt), and two review notifications popped up. Having spent ~20 mins editing, I thought nothing of it and clicked on it, only to be presented with no review tasks as per this screenshot.

[image: screenshot of the problem]

Comment: [status](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109630/230957)-[bydesign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197398/230957). That said, it's very annoying indeed.

Comment: I always assumed that someone else beat me to the punch and clicked first …